# Error in implementation of a stack with O(1) find-max/find-min?

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

I have implemented several functions for the Stack ADT. I am trying to find the max and min values in O(1) time and I have augmented my stack structure to serve this purpose. This is my code:

```
 void mms_push(MMStack mms, int i) {

struct llnode *new = malloc(sizeof(struct llnode));
new->item = i;
if(mms->len!=0)
{
 new->next = mms->topnode;
 mms->topnode = new;
}
else 
{
 new->next = NULL;
 mms->topnode = new;
}

if (mms->len == 0)
{
mms->topnode->minc = i;
mms->topnode->maxc = i;}
else
{
  if(mms->topnode->maxc < i)
  {
      mms->topnode->maxc = i;
  }

  if(i<mms->topnode->minc)
  {
      mms->topnode->minc = i;
  }


mms->len++;}


int mms_pop(MMStack mms) {
  assert(mms);
  int ret = mms->topnode->item;
  struct llnode *backup = mms->topnode;
  mms->topnode = mms->topnode->next;
  mms->len--;


  free(backup);
  return ret;
}
```

My structures used are as below:

```
struct llnode
{

  int item;
  struct llnode *next;
  int minc;
  int maxc;
};

struct mmstack
{
  int len ;
  struct llnode *topnode;

};


typedef struct mmstack *MMStack;
```

I am not getting the correct value of max and min values. How do I correct the code so that I get the right value of max and min element in the stack?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: c or c++? my bet is c.

Comment: Q: What do you mean by "not correct value"???

Comment: @luk32 i am sorry for not mentioning its in c

Comment: @FoggyDay these are the assertions i made(the last one is failing):   mms_push(mms, 10);
  mms_push(mms, 5);
  mms_push(mms, 20);
  assert(mms_max(mms) == 20);
  assert(mms_min(mms) == 5);

Comment: @LohitTalasila You tagged it both.

Comment: Check your pop function, shouldn't you update min and max there as well?  In general getting the min and the max from a stack does not sound like a good idea; a stack is a LIFO ADT.

Comment: You're comparing to the values in the new, uninitialised node.

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks for pointing it out, could you tell me how to correct it. I am unable to think of a way to fix it. please help

Comment: @zakkak i don't need to update the pop function as the idea behind this code, is that every node in the linked list has a max and min value which gives the max and min value of all the elements before/below it. so when you pop its automatically updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this code:

```
if (mms->len == 0)
{
  mms->topnode->minc = i;
  mms->topnode->maxc = i;
}
else
{
  if(mms->topnode->maxc < i)
  {
      mms->topnode->maxc = i;
  }

  if(i<mms->topnode->minc)
  {
      mms->topnode->minc = i;
  }
}
```

Notice that in the `else` branch, you're reading the values of `mms->topnode->minc` and `mms->topnode->maxc` before you've initialized them. I think you meant to look at the values of `mms->topnode->minc`/`maxc` before you reassigned `mms->topnode`. To fix this, try doing something like this:

```
else
{
  mms->topnode->maxc = mms->topnode->next->maxc;
  mms->topnode->minc = mms->topnode->next->minc;

  if(mms->topnode->maxc < i)
  {
      mms->topnode->maxc = i;
  }

  if(i<mms->topnode->minc)
  {
      mms->topnode->minc = i;
  }
}
```

These extra two lines initialize the min and max values to the old max values before comparing against `i`, which should ensure that they get a value.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot, your correction is very apt and exactly what i wanted. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing things a bit backwards — comparing `i` to the values in the new, uninitialised node after you have inserted it in the stack.

It's easier to first prepare the new node completely, and then link it into the stack.

Assuming that an empty stack has a `NULL` topnode:

```
void mms_push(MMStack mms, int i) {
   struct llnode *new = malloc(sizeof(struct llnode));
   new->item = i;
   new->next = mms->topnode;
   if (!mms->topnode)
   {
       new->minc = i;
       new->maxc = i;
   }
   else
   {
      new->minc = min(mms->topnode->minc, i);
      new->maxc = max(mms->topnode->maxc, i);
   }
   mms->topnode = new;
   mms->len++;
}
```

I'm not sure if `min` and `max` are C99, but they're trivial to define.